# Cannot GET /ejs file

Tags: html, node.js

I'm trying to get the stat of a survey page done with html
when I try to connect to the ejs view of the webpage it gives me Cannot GET /showResults

```
// Entry point for the application

// express application
var express = require('express');
// require the controller we make
var surveyController = require('./surveyController');

var app = express();

// set up template engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// static file serving
app.use(express.static('./public'));

// fire function from surveyController
surveyController(app);

// listen to port
app.listen(8080);
console.log('listening port 8080');
```

I have an HTML view of the webpage and app.js file that seem to run on the console but I get the error when I log into http://localhost:8080/showResults

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use `ejs` as you view by below settings in your `app.js`

```
// view engine setup

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

```
// use res.render to load up an ejs view file

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('<folder>/index');
});
```